# d3.js Lines with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to plot some lines using d3 and react.

Basically, when I get to my page, I have the following sample code:

```
class TimeSeries extends Component {
 render() {

   const cabra = this.props. myData
   const width = this.props.size[1]
   const height = this.props.size[0]

   const xScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 30])
     .range([0, this.props.size[0]])

   const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 60])
     .range([this.props.size[1], 0])

     const temperature = myData.temperature
     const humidity = myData.humidity

     const transfData = temperature.map((value,index) => {
       return {'indice':index,'value':value}
     })

     const sparkLine = d3.line()
       .x( d => xScale(d.indice) )
       .y( d => yScale(d.value) )

    let bic = transfData.map((v,i) => {
      console.log("Passing ",v,"to the sparkline function");
      return sparkLine(v)
      }
    )

    console.log("BIC",bic)

    const sparkLines = transfData.map((v,i) =>
  <path
    key={'line' + i}
    d={sparkLine(v)}
    className='line'
    style={{fill:'none',strokeWidth:2, stroke: "red"}}
  />)

return <svg width={width} height={height}>
    <g transform={"translate(0," + (-this.props.size[1] / 2) + ")"}>
       {sparkLines}
    </g>
   </svg>
   }
```

Besides not drawing the lines, The `BIC` part that was putted for test is printing an array of `undefined` values.

For more tests, I put some prints inside the line function:

```
       const sparkLine = d3.line()
       .x( d => { console.log("Being Called"); return(xScale(d.indice)) })
       .y( d => yScale(d.value) )
```

But this console.log is never being printed.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A d3 [line generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#_line) expects an array of data as the argument. For each item in that array your `.x()` and `.y()` functions will get called. From your example code it looks like you're passing each data point to the line generator.

Try passing in `transfData` instead and see if this fixes it for you:

```
const sparkLines = 
  <path
    key={'line' + i}
    d={sparkLine(transfData)}
    className='line'
    style={{fill:'none',strokeWidth:2, stroke: "red"}}
  />
```